# Script to enable caffeine-indicator

Tags: scripts, login

Caffeine-indicator works well for me when I activate it manually. Right now the coffee cup is always displayed on the panel. But I have to click it, which makes a 2nd indicator appear, and then select activate from this 2nd indicator's menu. The 2nd indicator then shows the steam indication and all is well.

But I'd like to cut out the manual steps. How can I script something to give me hot, steaming caffeine-indicator at login with no manual intervention?

Comment: Do you want the `caffeine-indicator` applet appear on startup?

Comment: I want it to be activated. I know how to autostart it but it requires manual activation.

Answer (score 2):

`caffeine-indicator` is a python script.  I also wanted it to auto-activate, so I edited it to do so.  `sudo vi /usr/bin/caffeine-indicator` then in the `class Caffeine()` `def __Init__()`  Add a last line in that function `self.toggle_activated()`